# multiplicity of algebraic connectivity.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, graph-theory, trees, algebraic-graph-theory

Suppose that $T$ is a tree with $n$ vertices and $L$ is the Laplacian matrix of $T$ and $0=\mu_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq \cdots \leq \mu_n$ are laplacian eigenvalues.

I think the multiplicity of $\mu_2$ can not be large.

For example I want to prove that:

If the multiplicity of $\mu_2$ in a tree $T$ be greater than $n/4$, then $T$ is the star $K_{1,n-1}$.

Any help can be useful for me.

Comment: I think you can prove it for some numbers other $n/4$. For example for $n/2$ etc. So it is better to put $\alpha$, $\alpha >n/4$, instead of $n/4$.